# Count Sort in C - Error: Use of undeclared identifier

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, counting

I am trying to code a Function that uses the Counting Sort algorithm, but when i try to compile it says that **output_array** and **count_array** are **undeclared**, even though I already declared them as int type arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "input_blatt01.h"

int MAX_LAENGE = 1000;
int MAX_VALUE = 100;
int i, k, j;
void count_sort_calculate_counts(int input_array[], int len, int count_array[])
{
    for (i=0; i<=len;i++)
    {
        count_array[i] = 0;
    }
    for (j=1; j<=len;j++)
    {
        count_array[input_array[j]] = count_array[input_array[j]] + 1;
    }
}

void count_sort_write_output_array(int output_array[], int len, int count_array[])
{
    k=0;
    for (j=1;j<=len;j++)
    {
        for (i=1; i<=count_array[j]; i++)
        {
            output_array[k] = j;
            k = k + 1;
        }
    }
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc < 2){
        printf("Aufruf: %s <Dateiname>\n", argv[0]);
        printf("Beispiel: %s zahlen.txt\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    char *filename = argv[1];

    int input_array[MAX_LAENGE];  
    int len = read_array_from_file(input_array, MAX_LAENGE, filename);

    printf("Unsortiertes Array:");
    print_array(input_array, len);
    int i, k, j;
    count_sort_calculate_counts(input_array, len, count_array);
    count_sort_write_output_array(output_array, len, count_array);

    printf("Sortiertes Array:");
    print_array(output_array, len);

    return 0;
}
```

**Compiler Output:**

> introprog_blatt01_aufgabe02_vorgabe.c:51:51: error: use of undeclared
>   identifier
>         'count_array'; did you mean 'print_array'?
>       count_sort_calculate_counts(input_array, len, count_array);
>
> ./input_blatt01.h:2:6: note: 'print_array' declared here void
>   print_array(int array[], int len);
>
> introprog_blatt01_aufgabe02_vorgabe.c:52:35: error: use of undeclared
>   identifier
>         'output_array'; did you mean 'input_array'?
>       count_sort_write_output_array(output_array, len, count_array);
>                                     introprog_blatt01_aufgabe02_vorgabe.c:45:9: note: 'input_array'
>   declared here
>       int input_array[MAX_LAENGE];
>
> introprog_blatt01_aufgabe02_vorgabe.c:52:54: error: use of undeclared
>   identifier
>         'count_array'; did you mean 'print_array'?
>       count_sort_write_output_array(output_array, len, count_array);
>
> ./input_blatt01.h:2:6: note: 'print_array' declared here void
>   print_array(int array[], int len);
>
> introprog_blatt01_aufgabe02_vorgabe.c:55:17: error: use of undeclared
>   identifier
>         'output_array'; did you mean 'input_array'?
>       print_array(output_array, len);
>
> introprog_blatt01_aufgabe02_vorgabe.c:45:9: note: 'input_array'
>   declared here
>       int input_array[MAX_LAENGE];

Comment: Show the exact output of the compiler. BTW I don't see any declaration of `output_array` and `count_array` in `main`. That's probably the answer to your question.

Comment: Beware off-by-one errors and accessing out of bounds elements in your loops. Array indexes start at `0` and go to `n - 1`. Some of your loops start at `1` (it may be right: I didn't study the code) and some include `n` as an array index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `output_array` and `count_array` as parameters of the functions below:

```
void count_sort_calculate_counts(int input_array[], int len, int count_array[])
void count_sort_write_output_array(int output_array[], int len, int count_array[])
```

But you didn't declare `output_array` and `count_array` in the `main` function.

You probbaly need this:

```
...
int input_array[MAX_LAENGE];  
int output_array[MAX_LAENGE];   // <<< add this
int count_array[MAX_LAENGE];    // <<< add this 
int len = read_array_from_file(input_array, MAX_LAENGE, filename);
...
```

Comment: Thank you! It finxed my problem, although now I got the error "Segmentation fault: 11", but thats probbalybecause i made some mistake with the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I see no declarations of output_array and count_array inside `main` function so it does not "know" about them. Read up on variable scopes. EDIT: I guess it can be remade so you can pass pointers to the arrays.

Comment: int input_array[] - i may have forgot everything, but as far as i remember int input_array[] will create an array just big enough to hold the data.